# C++: How can I access a method of an inner class?

Tags: c++, function, class, inner-classes

I was going through `classes` and thought of doing nested classes.So I have the below class declaration.

```
class myClass {
    public:
        void method1() {
            cout << "This is method 1" << endl;
        }
        class myClass2 {
            void method2() {
                cout << "This is method 2" << endl;
            }
        };
};
```

As you can see , `myClass` has a method `method2` in it.The code below works just fine and gives me the desired output.

```
myClass obj;
obj.method1();
```

But when I try this:

```
obj.method2();
```

I get the error message `method2 is not a member of myClass`.

**Questions:**

1. Why can't I access the method 'method2`from objects of class`myClass`?
2. Is there a way to access `method2`?

For Question 2 , I thought of creating an object of class `myClass2` in `myClass`, then make another function in `myClass` to access the `method2` function.

I want to know if there is any other way out, because my way seems a bit pain staking.

Comment: How is nested classes "out of the box"?

Comment: @Happy happy? I edited to your liking :)

Comment: @Downvoter , I dont get it ! I have a genuine doubt . Pls help instead of downvoting

Comment: I've upvoted this question ot because I think it's particularly good, but because it's a fair question that doesn't really deserve a downvote.

Comment: @einpoklum thx for the edit and the upvote :)

Comment: A lot of people here on SO are kind of mean, downvoting questions because you haven't asked them perfectly enough. They should just leave a comment and tell you to fix the question.

Comment: @einpoklum: That is an abuse of your voting privileges. You are supposed to vote on the content, not on others peoples' votes. You've explicitly said that you're not doing that. In short, it is not your job to "undo" other people's right to vote. That being said, I can't understand the downvotes in this case, either.

Comment: @einpoklum: Oh and your last comment is _wrong_. The voting mechanism exists for a reason. If nobody downvoted then what would be the point of it? How would we rank questions? It's _good_ that we can do that. Again, though, it seems to be broken in this instance because the question was never particularly bad. Although I'm not sure I can see it ever helping anyone else, which may have been the issue.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The site exists to help answer questions people have, not to ensure "true ranking" of questions according to quality. Downvoting people who have difficult expressing themselves because of this very problem has mostly the effect of discouraging them. But this is a discussion better fitting meta or chat.

Comment: @einpoklum: You're welcome to suggest on meta that the voting system be removed, but you won't get much traction. Quality questions and answers vising to the top via _voting_ is one of the fundamental tenets of this website: it's the entire purpose of its existence. The "true ranking" of quality _leads to_ helping people find good answers to good questions. But I feel that you should already know this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Nobody said the voting system should be removed. I'm saying it's being used unwisely in much of SO. The voting customs on, say, TeX.SX are more appropriate in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Because `Class2()` is not a member of `myClass`.

2) You need to instantiate a `myClass::myClass2` object and call the member on it. `myClass2::Class2()` is a member function, so it needs an object to act on. For example

```
myClass::myClass2 obj;
obj.Class2();
```

Note that this requires that you make `myClass2::Class2()` a public member. It is private in your code.

Comment: I am not quite aware on how to implement the 2) of your answer , could you let me know

Comment: @MohitBhasi I added an example.

Comment: `   myClass::myClass2 obj;
   obj.Class2();` I get an error

Comment: It says the function is not accessible

Comment: @MohitBhasi That is because you made it private. Make it public.

Comment: Ok , i just need to add public in myClass2 THX IT WORKS!

Comment: Wait , another question . If i havent put an access specifier does the function , by default , be private?

Comment: @MohitBhasi The default is `private` for `class`, and `public` for `struct`. I usually use `struct` if it saves typing.

Comment: I think i am going to delete this question because everyone seems to be downvoting it

Comment: @MohitBhasi No problem. I don't understand the down-votes BTW.

Comment: Hey 1 more thing , I just realised that I cant access class1 function with the type of object u have suggested in your answer

Comment: so then i will have to create a separate object for myclass then. ok thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Putting `class2` inside of `class1` does less than you think it does. It does nothing more than put it in `class1`'s scope.

So, imagine the same thing but not nested:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    void Class1()
    {
        cout<<"This is Class 1"<<endl;
    }
};
class myClass2
{
public:
    void Class2()
    {
        cout<<"This is Class 2"<<endl;
    }
};

...

// and this should look normal to you:
myClass obj;
obj.Class1();

myClass2 obj2;
obj2.Class2();
```

Now put `myClass2` in `myClass` scope, like you did, and see how the last few lines change.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    void Class1()
    {
      cout<<"This is Class 1"<<endl;
    }
    class myClass2
    {
    public:
        void Class2()
        {
            cout<<"This is Class 2"<<endl;
        }
    };
};

...

myClass obj;
obj.Class1();

myClass::myClass2 obj2;// this is the only thing that changes. You put myClass2 in a different scope.
obj2.Class2();
```

So to answer your questions directly:

> 1) Why cant I access the function Class2 using the myClass obj.

Because `Class2` is not a member of `myClass`. It's a member of `myClass2`, which you need to instantiate just like you did with `myClass`.

> 2) Is there a way to access Class2 function.

Yes, by instantiating a `myClass2`, like at the end of my example: `myClass::myClass2 obj2; obj2.Class2();`.